# apns in production environment

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app is finally on the App store (thanks to stack overflow :))

Now i'm facing a new problem, everything was ok when i pushed in dev environment, now i can't push anyone, so i have one question :

does a pass phrase is required for production environment ?

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'mycert.pem');

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

Thanks to all

Comment: The code you included refers to the sandbox apns server

Comment: yea i know that thank you, i've managed to push how can you close a question ?